# I created my own smart pointer class, I used this smart pointer to point to a class instance, how can I properly return the smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am new to C++ and trying to implement some of the methods.

I created a smart pointer class, CarPtr, as following:

```
template <class Car>
class CarPtr
{
public:
    Car *ptr;  // Actual pointer
   // Constructor
   explicit CarPtr(Car *p = nullptr) { ptr = p; }
   // Destructor
   ~CarPtr() { delete(ptr); cout << "CarPtr destructor" << endl;}
   // Overloading dereferencing operator
   Car &operator *() {  return *ptr; }
   Car *operator -> () { return ptr; }
};

#endif /* CARPTR_H_ */
```

Then I created an instance of the Car class and used my smart pointer to point at it.

```
CarPtr<Car> carInfoCreation()
{
    CarPtr<Car> p(new Car());
    int carId;
    int carYear;
    double carCost;
    String carMake;
    String carModel;
    cout << "please enter the Id for the car" << endl;
    cin >> carId;
    p.ptr->setId(carId);

    cout << "please enter the Year for the car" << endl;
    cin >> carYear;
    p.ptr->setYear(carYear);

    cout << "please enter the Cost for the car" << endl;
    cin >> carCost;
    p.ptr->setCost(carCost);

    cout << "please enter the Make for the car" << endl;
    cin >> carMake;
    p.ptr->setMake(carMake);
    String getMake = p.ptr->getMake();

    cout << "please enter the Model for the car" << endl;
    cin >> carModel;
    p.ptr->setModel(carModel);
    String getModel = p.ptr->getModel();

    cout << "Car Info: " << endl;
    cout << "Car Id: "<< p.ptr->getId() << endl;
    cout << "Car Year: "<< p.ptr->getYear() << endl;
    cout << "Car Cost: " << p.ptr->getCost() << endl;
    cout << "Car Make: " << getMake << endl;
    cout << "Car Model: " << getModel << endl;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("Car 1.txt");
    myfile << "Car Id: " << carId << endl;
    myfile << "Car Year: " << carYear << endl;
    myfile << "Car Cost: " << carCost << endl;
    myfile << "Car Make: " << carMake << endl;
    myfile << "Car Model: " << carModel << endl;
    myfile.close();

    return p;
}
```

After creating the instance, I wish to return the smart pointer p and put it in a smart pointer array I created as following:

```
CarPtr<Car> CarPtrArray[5];
CarPtrArray[0] = carInfoCreation() ;
```

After I run the code, the instance was successfully created, I can see the corresponding .txt file. But right after that, I will see the error shown by Eclipse:

"xxx.exe has stopped working

A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Can anybody help me to solve this problem? If you need more code or relating information just let me know.

Thank you very much!

Comment: When carInfoCreation returned your smartPointer p destructer called and it will release the acquired resources.You should read about unique_ptr and shared_ptr.

Comment: "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. " is codespeak for "Run this in your debugger"

Comment: Your class needs to follow the Rule of Three/Five/Zero. Without that, returning one by value as you do leads to undefined behaviour

Comment: Hi @M.M., thank you for your advice, I added overloaded copy constructor and assignment operator in my smart pointer class. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @HHY OK, I'll write an answer so you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class needs to follow [the Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Without that, returning one by value as you do leads to undefined behaviour: the pointer will be deleted when the temporary return object is destroyed (and/or the local object being returned), but then the calling code carries on using the pointer.